# Liquibase: Communications link failure

Tags: terminal, liquibase

I try to run Liquibase from terminal:

Command:

```
user@Host ~/Development/Liquibase $ java -jar liquibase.jar --changeLogFile=ChangeLog/create.xml --username=root --password=Pass123 --url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.8:3306/Semafor --classpath=lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar update
Unexpected error running Liquibase: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

Ping to host:

```
~/Documents/Development/Liquibase $ ping 192.168.1.8
PING 192.168.1.8 (192.168.1.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.29 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell, but it may be that while you can ping the host, other communications is blocked by a firewall or similar. You should check that the MySQL port is open.